Finding minimum area of a triangle formed by intersection of tangent to an ellipse
Question:
The tangent at the point $\theta$ to the curve $(x,y)=(a\cos\theta,b\sin\theta)$ meets the $x$-axis at $A$ and $y$-axis at $B$. If $O$ is origin. Find minimum area of $\triangle AOB$.
What I have tried

Using the general equation of the ellipse, I have got the equation of the tangent at the given points.
Then using the equation of the tangent at $B(0,y)$, I got the value of $y$ as $b/\sin\theta$ and also did the same at $A(x,0)$ and got $x$ as $a/\cos\theta$.
from there I got distance $OB$ and $OA$ and then used the equation $\frac12\times\mathrm{base}\times\mathrm{height}$ to get the area. The expected answer is supposed to be $ab$.


Please include the question in the body of the post?

What's your result for the area?

You should have an expression for the triangle area as a function of $\theta$. Now you have to find the value of $\theta$ which minimizes that function. Where are you stuck? (Hint: when the area is minimum, the reciprocal of the area is maximum).

Hint #2: $\cos\theta\sin\theta = \frac{1}{2}\sin(2\theta)$.
